# Is it possible to modify .docx files through client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, github, ms-word, docx

Im trying to add/remove lines to an existing .docx file through the browser. I've found docx.js that's able to create .docx files from scratch but isn't able to modify already existing ones. Haven't been able to find a solution yet, is one there?

I've surfed Google and GitHub without any results for a client-side processing of this

Comment: I had a similar task and was unable to find an adequate solution. I ended up modifying a fork of https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater to fit my needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I believe that could work for what I'm trying to accomplish and seems to work client-side.

Comment: Good luck with your project!